# sort the objects in array that has same value to one object inside the same array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, javascript-objects

I am making Fetch request that return array of objects as follow:

```
[
   {"id":11,"name":"test1","day":"MON","level":2},
   {"id":13,"name":"test2","day":"TUE","level":3},
   {"id":14,"name":"test1","day":"WED","level":4},
   {"id":15,"name":"test2","day":"FRI","level":5}
]
```

So, inside this array I have four objects  each two have the same name, so I want the result to be like this:

```
 {
           "test1" : [
                       {"id":11,"name":"test1","day":"MON","level":2}, 
                       {"id":14,"name":"test1","day":"WED","level":4}
                    ],
           "test2" :[
                      {"id":13,"name":"test2","day":"TUE","level":3}, 
                      {"id":15,"name":"test2","day":"FRI","level":5}
                    ]
  }
```

Comment: that makes sense now. What you're looking for is `groupby`. Sadly JS doesn't provide a built in method for this, as it's such a common task, but you'll find like a million results/answers if you search for it here on SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a reduce function

```js
const arr = [
   {"id":11,"name":"test1","day":"MON","level":2},
   {"id":13,"name":"test2","day":"TUE","level":3},
   {"id":14,"name":"test1","day":"WED","level":4},
   {"id":15,"name":"test2","day":"FRI","level":5}
];

const result = arr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    acc[cur.name] = acc[cur.name] || [];
  acc[cur.name].push(cur);
  return acc;
}, {})

console.log(result);
console.log(Object.values(result).flat());
```

Comment: i noticed that the `result` it printed as object how to make it as array

Comment: in your question, you mentioned that you wanted an object. am I right?

Comment: yes sir you are right, but if you don't mind of how to do that I will appreciate it. thanks

Comment: how would the array look like? I thought object (as you have expected) makes more sense

Comment: I am sorry about that, it is a bit confusing, I thought of array coz I want to print the values of the result that I got from your answer `test1 and test2` inside `FlatList` in react native, but I am not sure may there another way to do it. thanks

Comment: no problem, I have added a liner in my solution to output array